# jquery xml parsing foreach

Tags: jquery, xml, foreach

I need to get data from xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xml>
    <User>
     <Agent>
      <id>cr4523</id>
     </Agent>
     <Time>
        <Time_Main>2-3pm</Time_Main>
        <Day>Mon</Day>
        <Time_Main>3-4pm</Time_Main>
        <Day>Mon</Day>
        <Time_Main>10-11am</Time_Main>
        <Day>Tue</Day>
      </Time>
     </User>
     </xml>
```

My problem is that a: not sure if my xml file is correctly formatted and b: the jquery I am using compressess all the data together, albiet in 'Time_Main' sections and 'Day' sections.

What I require is for each Time_Main and Day I need to call a simple function.

The jquery I am using is -

```
    $(html).find('Time').each(function(){
        var day=$(this).find('Day').text();
    var time_main=$(this).find('Time_Main').text();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, *formatting* is correct, but *structuring* not (I assume that Time/Day pairs are to be chosen as single entity).
I'll do then:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
<User>
  <Agent>
     <id>cr4523</id>
  </Agent>
  <Time>
     <Time_Main>2-3pm</Time_Main>
     <Day>Mon</Day>
  </Time>
  <Time>
     <Time_Main>3-4pm</Time_Main>
     <Day>Mon</Day>
  </Time>
 </User>
 </xml>
```

From this you can loop through all the "Time" tags and retrieve `Time_Main` and `Day`.

```
$(html).find("Time").each(
        function (i,e)
        {
            console.log("New time tag...");
            console.log($(e).find("time_main").text());
            console.log($(e).find("day").text());
        }

        );
```

If you still need a **single** `Time` tag, wrap `Time_main`/`Day` couples in another tag:

```
<Time>
   <TimeGroup>
     <Time_Main>2-3pm</Time_Main>
     <Day>Mon</Day>
  </TimeGroup>
  <TimeGroup>
     <Time_Main>3-4pm</Time_Main>
     <Day>Mon</Day>
  </TimeGroup>
 </Time>

$(html).find("Time TimeGroup").each(
        function (i,e)
        {
            console.log("New time tag...");
            console.log($(e).find("time_main").text());
            console.log($(e).find("day").text());
        }

        );
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems to make the data easier to run through even  without looping.

Comment: Yes, you had the data flat becaus data was flat indeed... if my assumption was right, and time/data go in pairs, this is the best and easiest way to deal with the scenario